# Run multiple File Reader and the library connected to them synchronously

Tags: javascript, filereader, multiple-file-upload

https://jsfiddle.net/b3pxcru1/
Hi everyone, I have a problem with the following script.

```
Thanks to the input, I indicate multiple files by selecting it from the fyle system.
After that, I create an instance of the FileReader object and add a function that manages the load event referred to the object itself.
At the end of the upload, as many audio tracks are generated as the elements selected at the time of input.
Finally, the readAsDataURL() method allows to access the contents of the files.
What I would like to achieve is that the library that allows me to extrapolate the track's tags wait the end of the loading ONE TRACK AT A TIME before being read, by running the script synchronous, according to a scheme like this:
TRACK 1 LOADED;
TAGS TRACK 1 LOADED;
TRACK 2 LOADED;
TAGS TRACK 2 LOADED.
TRACK 3 LOADED;
TAGS TRACK 3 LOADED.
Currently, something like this happens when upload multiple files:
TRACK 2 LOADED;
TAGS TRACK 1 LOADED;
TRACK 1 LOADED;
TAGS TRACK 3 LOADED.
TRACK 3 LOADED;
```

if I load a single file, the library is executed before the creation of the audio tag, whose reference variable (create_audio) remains undefined, so the audio tags cannot be read since it doesn't exist yet
the track.

I believe that the solution is to use Promises; I studied them but, in the specific case, I have no idea how implement them.
Can you help me to make it?
Thanks

https://github.com/aadsm/JavaScript-ID3-Reader link to the library I'm using

Comment: ID3-Reader is kinda depricated, use [jsmediatags](https://github.com/aadsm/jsmediatags), they have a method for reading files/blob without having to use FileReader

Comment: Does the library require Node.js?

Comment: it can work in both node and browser